# Django: icontains case is sensitive for unicode

Tags: python, django, unicode, django-models, search-engine

I'm making a simple search for my blog. I use an armenian language and when I'm searching it's always sensetive for these letters. Here is a part of my code. Thank you in advance.

```
search_query = get.get('search')
query_list = search_query.split()
posts = post.objects.filter(
                reduce(operator.and_,
                       (Q(title__icontains=q) for q in query_list))|
                reduce(operator.and_,
                       (Q(content__icontains=q) for q in query_list)),
            )
```

Comment: what's your database, and what's the collation used ?

Comment: I use sqlite3 and I didn't setting up it. I understud that I had to, but what settings I have to set?

Comment: I'm afraid there's not much you can do with sqlite3 (at least nothing that's worth the pain).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is generaly just problem with SQLite, problem is described in details on documentation link, also there is a link getting back to original SQLite site description

From django [icontains](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#icontains) documentation

> SQLite users
>
> When using the SQLite backend and non-ASCII strings, bear in mind the
>   database note about [string comparisons](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/databases/#substring-matching-and-case-sensitivity).

[SQLite documentation regarding following problem](https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q18)